# Problem with contents of WebView in Android

Tags: android, flash, webview

I created a WebView in android inside an Activity of an TabActivity

but when I load the contents inside the WebView and I scroll the WebView (that is not full screen) or I change the tab, some contents of WebView like flash scripts or built-in controls
do not disappear covering the elements of the layout

I tried to disable plugins in WebView without success, and I need the zoom function so I have to keep the built-in controls enabled

how can I solve this? thanks

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to say.

Comment: I have a webview in my android application layout and some contents of this view like flash or zoom controls remain visible even when shwiching views (like a z-index = 9999999)